# Fetch spark job jar from Nexus

Tags: apache-spark, nexus

Is it possible to get spark to fetch the primaryResource jar from Nexus given the maven coordinates for it? I know it is possible to fetch dependencies from Nexus, but it doesn't appear to be possible to fetch the job jar from Nexus. I'm wondering if anyone else has tried it or has a workaround for the same. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this a req't? The system will need to download and/or upload the JAR w/ all it's dependencies before it even executes. In my experience, it doesn't cache it. So, it will have to do it for every execution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like `spark-submit` works with just `--packages` and `--repositories` and a dummy `primaryResource`.

The example:

```
--packages someGroupId:someArtifactId:someVersion \
--repositories http://nexus.company.com/nexus nonExistentFakeName.jar
```

Comment: what do you mean by dummy primaryResource?

Comment: Dummy meaning anything - doesn't have to be a real jar - just any name (to get past `spark-submit` argument checks)

Comment: So you are able to get the job jar file from Nexus? If so, can you please share the command you used

Comment: If the nexus proxies are setup properly to pull dependencies, `spark-submit --packages com.company.blah.blah --repositories http://nexus.company.com/nexus dummy.jar` should work just fine.

Comment: How are you specifying the maven coordinates like group ID, artifact ID and version

Comment: Specify the maven coordinate as a `:` separated string (eg: `com.company:artifactId:version`) From the Spark docs: Users may also include any other dependencies by supplying a comma-delimited list of maven coordinates with --packages. All transitive dependencies will be handled when using this command. Additional repositories (or resolvers in SBT) can be added in a comma-delimited fashion with the flag --repositories. These commands can be used with pyspark, spark-shell, and spark-submit to include Spark Packages.

Comment: In my experience, the "primary" JAR needs to exist. I think it doesn't need to be a real JAR but it does need to be a real file.